# How can I fix my Microphone In while running Hyper-V?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

There seems to be an odd issue with Hyper-V on AMD machines and the Microphone In. As developer I installed Hyper-V for the usage of the Windows Phone 8 SDK. A side effect is that the Microphone In since then is not working anymore - lots of static noise.
You can of course turn off Hyper-V as Windows feature or go to the BIOS to deactivate conditions which are necessary to use Hyper-V. After that the Mic In is working again. 
Most solutions in the Internet suggest turning of the BIOS features but that doesn't really works, because then you cannot use the Hyper-V.

Is there any solution to this problem? I do need both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with audio playback couple years ago (Windows Server 2008). The problem was that my system did not support Second Level Address Translation ([SLAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation)). Therefore the Hyper-V layer needs to work harder and discard the CPU page tables when swapping running OS. That causes jitter in anything that requires real-time processing.

I believe that Windows 8 requires SLAT to enable Hyper-V (see [this](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-8/q-while-trying-enable-hyper-v-my-windows-8-computer-why-does-it-say-my-processor-doesnt-ha)). You probably have a different problem then. Perhaps there is a better driver available for your audio hardware?

Comment: Yes, my system has SLAT. But good idea, I will look if there are new drivers for my system.